# Can complex type be inherited?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have table Contacts with columns:

- LinkType (1 means link with Card, 2 means link with Firm)
- FirmId (nullable)
- CardId (nullable)
- Value

So, Contact can be linked with Card or with Firm (not both). Contact can change it link (from Card to Firm and vice versa).
I want to map it in classes like this:

```
class Contact
{
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public Link ContactLink {get;set;}
}

class ContactLink
{

}

class CardLink : ContactLink
{
    public long CardId {get;set;}
}

class FirmLink : ContactLink
{
    public long FirmId {get;set;}
}
```

`ContactLink` is not an entity (there is no table for it).

There is only one table `Contact`.

Can I map all these classes to one table?
Is it possible to map these complex types with inheritance? How can I make it?

**Additional info:**

When I create two classes `FirmContact` and `CardContact`, I map them with discriminator column. But I can't change in code object type from `FirmContact` to `CardContact` to save it.

Comment: normally, if you use `ContactLink` in `Contact` (you aren't doing that right now) entity framework should add you a `discriminator` in your database.

Comment: @Tikkes, yes. Another way: create 2 classes (FirmContact and CardContact) and map them with discriminator column. But, I can't change type of object from CardContact to FirmContact to save it

Comment: What type of mapping are you using? Fluent Api or Data Annotation?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev fluent api, but any ideas are welcome